# How get multiple BooleanFields in a form using Django

Tags: django

I have a form in my site to get a report about some "collective payment". It has 3 main field: Value, date of payment and who paid.

The field "who paid" is a table containing the name of all users and a checkbox.

Currently I'm looping over all users, adding their full names to the table with a single checkbox. But I don't know how to get this data in my form associating it with each user name (just the text).

How can I get multiple BooleanFields in my form ? Is there a way of associate each BooleanField with an user's name?

**model.py**

```
from django.db import models

#created_date attibute needs it
from django.utils import timezone
# This Model is a super class "Financial Transaction"
class GroupTransaction(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=257, default='')
    who_paid = models.CharField(max_length=257, default='')
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    justification = models.CharField(max_length=257, default='')

    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    date = models.CharField(max_length=257, default='')
    receipt = models.FileField(upload_to='comprovantes', blank=True, null=True)
    its_type = models.CharField(max_length=257, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        #INCOMPLETOreturn "%s fez a movimentação financeira de %d para %s no dia " % (self.name, self.restaurant)
        return "%s - %s" % (self.name , self.who_paid)
```

**view.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from deposit.forms import DepositForm,MonthlyDepositForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your views here.
@login_required
def deposito(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DepositForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            HttpResponseRedirect('/historico/')
        else:
            print (str(form.errors.as_data()))
    else:
        form = DepositForm()
        groupForm = MonthlyDepositForm()
    return render(request, 'shell/app_shell.html', {
        'is_deposit' : True,
        'title' : 'Deposit',
        'transaction' : form,
        'groupTransaction' : groupForm,
        'users': User.objects.all()
    })
```

**form.py**

```
class MonthlyDepositForm(forms.ModelForm):
    value = forms.DecimalField()
    date = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class':'datepicker picker__input',
        'readonly':'',
        'tabindex':'54',
        'aria-haspopup':'True',
        'aria-expanded':'false',
        'aria-readonly':'false',
        'aria-owns':'birthdate_root'
        }))
    who_paid = forms.BooleanField()

    its_type = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(attrs={'readonly':True}),
                                initial='Deposito Mensal')


    class Meta:
        model = GroupTransaction
        fields = ('value', 'date','who_paid','its_type')
```

**template.html:**

```
<form class="col s12">

  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ groupTransaction.its_type }}
  <div class="row"></div>

  <!-- Nome do evento -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s6">
      <!-- <input id="nome_evento" type="number" value="10" step="any" min="0.05" max="400" class="validate" required> -->
      {{ groupTransaction.value }}
      <label for="nome_evento">Value</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s6">
      <!-- <input type="text" class="datepicker picker__input" readonly="" tabindex="54" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-owns="birthdate_root" required> -->
      {{ groupTransaction.date }}
      <label for="data-mensal" data-error="Data inválida">Date</label>
    </div>
  </div>




  <!-- Petianos que irão para o evento -->
  <table class="striped">
    <thead>
      <!-- Cabeçalho tabela -->
      <tr>
        <th>Who Paid</th>
        <th>
          <div class="switch">
            <b class="center-align">Default</b>
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox">
              <span class="lever"></span>
            </label>
          </div>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <!-- ============= -->
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      {% for user in users %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ user.get_full_name }}</td>
        <td>
          <div class="switch">
            <label>
              <!-- <input type="checkbox"> -->
              {{ groupTransaction.who_paid }}
              <span class="lever"></span>
            </label>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>

  <!-- Botão de registrar saque (submit) -->

  <div class="row">
      <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light col s6 m3 offset-s6 offset-m9 blue" type="submit" name="action">Submit
        <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
      </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

**How the form is:**

[image: How the form is]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `who_paid` a `ManyToManyField(User)`. Then in the form you can set its widget like this:

```
class Meta:
    model = GroupTransaction
    fields = ('value', 'date','who_paid','its_type')
    widgets = {
        'who_paid': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
    }
```

That will give you the right structure. Then you can render it manually if you want to change the display.